# share files from virtualbox guest to win7 host except through networking

Tags: virtualbox

The virtualbox additions make a way to share files form the host OS to the guest, but the files and directories from Win host doesn't support file links on guest well, so I work with files on the guest OS directly.Now I want sharing some files on the guest OS to the host for quickly editing, and I know some ways through networking:

- FTP/SFTP, using some ftp client with auto translation after saving
- NFS, share the directory through networking and mount it as remote network disk.

Is there a simple way to do it? :P

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on your guest machine in virtualbox when it is not running to set up your share folder. On a linux guest, it will be auto-mounted at /media/sf_YourFolderName. For other guest OS, read the virtualbox docs.

To know more, read this article on how to setup different networking and sharing scenarios between a virtualbox guest and the host: http://prahladyeri.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/how-to-setup-a-virtual-lan-on-your-machine-using-oracle-virtualbox/